# How to take data from another dataframe based on 2 columns

Tags: python, dataframe

Here is my code

```
A['period_id'] = A['period_number','Session'].map(B.set_index(['period_number','Session'])['period_id'])
```

So I want to take data from column `period_id`  of B to give to A, based on criteria that 2 columns (`period_number` and `Session`) are matched. However it gave me error. What can I do?

Comment: Look at using `merge`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge`:

```
A_columns = A.columns
A_columns.append("period_id")

# merge based on period_number and Session
merged_df = pd.merge(A, B,  how='left', left_on=['period_number','Session'], right_on = ['period_number','Session'])

final_df = merged_df[A_columns] # filter for only columns in A + `period_id` from B
```

Note that if `A`'s column names are different for `period_number` and `Session`, you'll have to adjust your `left_on`, and vice versa for `B`. To be explicit `A` is the left dataframe here, and `B` is the right dataframe.